# Best solution to notify back-end server about changes on client side

Tags: http, websocket, long-polling

There are about a thousand clients (mobile application).
There is a server (we are going to use SpringBoot), which saves information about changes on the client side.
Changes from each client to the server should arrive every 5 minutes.
Please tell me the best way to realise it:

- use simple http requests to the server
- use websocket
- use long polling

I can’t understand what is more critical, to keep a large number of connections or to respond to a large number of requests.